# Why is this oscilating circuit not possible

Tags: oscillator, basic

In my mind, this circuit should oscillate because the transistor draws the entire power when turned on. This, in turn, should cause the base to turn off, opening it back up and continuing the cycle. I must be gravely misunderstanding a concept here.
[image]

Comment: Also, terms such as "open" and "closed" are not normally used. They are ambiguous. What do you really mean?

Comment: if i apply a current to the base pin of a transistor it allows current to pass from the collector to the emmiter (in case of npn) correct me if im wrong here but would you call it open or close in this case?

Comment: @Tron A switch that is conducting (turned on) is called closed. A switch that is not conducting (turned off) is called open. This is the reverse of how they're used in most things, so we discourage using the terms "open" and "closed" to refer to switches, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: It might also help you understand why this doesn't oscillate if you realize that, while a transistor *can* act like a switch, it doesn't *always* act like a switch. It's not always going to be either "open" or "closed"; it can be in between the two as well.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the termonology up! So what you're saying is the current splits up between base and collector so that the circuit is always closed. if this is the case what 
term would i need lookup to understand which way electricity takes in these cases or rather how the current behaves?

Comment: @Tron don't use the term `closed` ... use the term `conducting`

Comment: Open, no, closed, no. Activated, yes, deactivated, yes, open-circuit, yes, short-circuit, yes. Please don't use terms that hydraulic/pneumatic people use.

Comment: sure i've got it not gonna happen again

Comment: It can "oscillate" (must add some component) ... "some" time, the it stops ...

Comment: "the transistor draws the entire power when turned on." - No, it doesn't.  Some power is dissipated in the 4.7K resistor.  (Reference designators - !)

Answer (score 2):

You think the inductor works somehow stepwise i.e. it takes some time the signal to travel through the inductor. Unfortunately that's not true. The current through the inductor changes smoothly and it happens at the same time at both ends of the inductor. Some balance is found and the starting transient dies off. In oscillator theory terms one could say "the feedback path does not cause enough phase lag" , The amp inverts the phase, so in theory 180 degrees feedback phase lag is needed, but a single inductor  causes less than 90 degrees.

It's well possible that there are some parasite capacitances in the coil and in the transistor and there's some inductance in the wiring, too so that the resulted LC circuit causes enough phase lag and the circuit oscillates assuming the tansistor works at high enough frequency.

A side note: At hundreds of megahertzes or higher frequencies special rf design calculations are needed to get some actual gain from amplifiers and at the same time to prevent them oscillating.

Something concrete to see:

If we change a long enough piece of coaxial cable to the place of the inductor it will oscillate because the coaxial cable has the propagation delay that you assumed in your stepwise thinking. A simulation example:

[image]

[image]

There's about 200 meters of 50 Ohm coaxial cable as T1. It takes some time to build up the oscillation due its 1us delay and the high resistance of R1. But continuous oscillation starts at about 20 us from switching the DC power (+5V) ON. The transistor is 2N1711 and the calculated curve is the voltage of node 2.

If you do not assume any wiring and inductor non-idealities you can get an oscillating circuit by changing the inductor to a LC circuit which causes enough phase lag at some frequency where the transistor has still some gain. At least the next circuit oscillates (tried by simulation):

[image]

As oscillator designs my both circuits are purely idiotic. They do not output even approximately clean sinewave and they have too many or too high cost parts when compared to clever designs.

As an advantage the coaxial cable version has quite well predictable frequency, but hundreds of meters coaxial cable to get a 500 kHz oscillator is probably too much. The situation would be different if the frequency were much higher.